# C# Console application fail to connect SQL Server every first time after rebuild

Tags: c#, console-application, sql-server-2014

I have a C# console application in `Main()`
I have

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    var connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HQMemberConnStr"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {
        conn.Open();

        // some modification to DB
    }
    scope.Complete();
}
```

Every time I rebuild the project and run the exe file by double click.
I get the following exception.

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while
>   establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or
>   was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that
>   SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named
>   Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server.

Weirdly, after the console close. If I double click the exe file again.
It works fine since then.
Well, until I rebuild project again then I will have that exception at the first time I run the application again which is pretty annoying.

Moreover, If I rebuild then run the application by Visual Studio 2013 it behaves correctly.

I have tested the comment part. No matter I comment them or not It seem like it has nothing to do with the problem.

I also close the firewall to check if it has something to do with the problem but didn't get lucky.

I want to make it behave right every single time but I'm not sure what I did wrong.

My App.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="HQMemberConnStr" 
         connectionString="Server=.;Database=HQMember;User Id=sa;Password=****;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

My .net version is 4.5
SQL Server Enterprise x64

Comment: Did you try to output (to console) and check the connection string right before calling `Open()`?

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya: Due to the code posted and the problem described this error occurs in line `conn.Open()`. If you regularly program with EF  and SQL Server this is a well-known error message which always happens in `.Open()` and a wrong configured connection string or a not running SQL server. Nevertheless here it is not so easy, cause the error disappears on the second run of the tool without changing the App.config (as far as I can read from the question).

Comment: Could some sort of anti-virus program be causing problems eg scanning new programs before allowing them to access the network?

Comment: @Oliver I'll try to output the connection string to see if I can find some clue maybe tomorrow morning(It's 9 PM now in my country). thx for the advice. and you get it right. The problem disappears after the first run and could be reproduced by rebuilding the project.

Comment: @sgmoore Interesting point, my computer has f-secure. I will try to close it to see if it leads the problem. However, my SQL Server for development is installed on the local machine so I guess it might not be the reason.

Comment: The connection string seems correct before `.Open()`

Comment: @sgmoore Guess what? You are right! After I temporarily shut down everything related to f-secure. It worked fine first run after rebuild! If you post an answer I will accept it happily!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try disabling your anti-virus program.

It could be causing problems eg scanning new programs before allowing them to access the network.